# Is this way of writing the Field and Order Axioms correct?

Tags: logic, field-theory, real-numbers, ordered-fields

I am currently self-studying math and am trying to write a Mathematics Cheat Sheet document that among other things includes the Field and Order Axioms. I want to write them as succinct as possible (preferably using logic notation) to not take much space and also to not use too many texts/words. Is this way of writing the axioms correct? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that $\underline\vee$ stands for the [XOR binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), there's the issue that $A\underline\vee B\underline \vee C$ is not the predicate that is true if and only if exactly one of the predicates is true: it's the predicate that is true if and only if *the number of true predicates is odd*. So your trichotomy doesn't work in the current form.

Comment: @sassatelli-giulio I was wondering about that. So what you're implying is that the statement is true if strictly one of them is true or three of them is true? And if so, is there any way I can correct my notation without using words? Thank you.

Comment: The field axioms are missing their quantifiers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson . Yes. But a literary stylist might argue that the $\forall$ in the title-line is "understood". (That would make the $\forall$ in the Order Axioms redundant.)... It should also say $a\ne 0\implies \exists! a^{-1}(aa^{-1}=1).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you don't need the ! in your existence; it follows from the other axioms.